# Re-arrange a MySQL nested query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How can i redo the following query to use only JOINs instead of the nested query?

```
SELECT SUM(allqty) AS allqty
    ,COUNT(*) AS orders 
FROM (SELECT SUM(S.Qty) AS allqty
      FROM data_intra.yw1_ordersheet S
      INNER  JOIN data_intra.productdata P ON P.productid=S.productid
      WHERE P.eCode LIKE (SELECT eCode
                          FROM data_intra.productdata
                          WHERE productid=1001)
      GROUP BY S.OrderPO) as A;
```

Comment: The current query is flawed, you will always get a count of 1. Could you tell us what it is you really want to count? The number of orders? the distinct number of products? Remember we know nothing about those tables & fields.

Comment: You can remove the count(*) part. Its not necessary. Just consider the remainder of the query.

Comment: Provide us the structure of your tables and a sample of data, that will help us to provide you a solution to your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 guesses. Both use IN() instead of LIKE()

This will produce one row for each S.OrderPO

```
SELECT
      SUM(S.Qty) AS allqty
    , S.OrderPO
FROM data_intra.yw1_ordersheet S
      INNER JOIN data_intra.productdata P
                  ON P.productid = S.productid
WHERE P.eCode IN (
            SELECT
                  eCode
            FROM data_intra.productdata
            WHERE productid = 1001
      )
GROUP BY
      S.OrderPO
;
```

This will produce one row, counting the distinct number of S.OrderPO

```
SELECT
      SUM(S.Qty)                AS allqty
    , COUNT(DISTINCT S.OrderPO) AS orders
FROM data_intra.yw1_ordersheet S
      INNER JOIN data_intra.productdata P
                  ON P.productid = S.productid
WHERE P.eCode IN (
            SELECT
                  eCode
            FROM data_intra.productdata
            WHERE productid = 1001
      )
;
```